# Is it proper to use the term "global" in a relative sense?

Tags: variables, global-variables, scope, local-variables

Please assume the following contrived JavaScript:

```
function do_something() {

  var x = 5;

  function alert_x() {
    alert(x);
  }

  alert_x();

}

do_something();
```

The variable `x` is local to the function `do_something`. It isn't a global variable because it's not available in every scope (i.e., outside of either of the functions, such as where `do_something` is called).

However, would it be proper to say that "the variable `x` is global to the function `alert_x`? Can "global" be used as a relative term in this sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend against doing this: it goes against convention and invites confusion. If you're doing this as part of the standard Javascript object idiom, just refer to `x` as a "member variable", or else as a "closure variable" (since it's captured by closure in `alert_x`).

Comment: Great to know, and that answers my question - thanks, JSBangs!